# How to "npm install" bcrypt on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, windows, bcrypt

I've installed node.js v6.9.1 together with npm version 4.1.2 and I've already used this combination for some projects

Now I wanted to use the `bcrypt` npm package in my project, but the installation fails miserably

```
npm install bcrypt --save
```

I've also tried to run this command with admin priviledges, to no avail

This is the error I get

```
> bcrypt@1.0.2 install C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcry
pt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcryp
t.js/releases/download/v1.0.2/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.2-node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.2 and node@6.9.1 (
node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_c
onfig_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\ttheiner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin
\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" clean )  else (node
"" clean )

C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_c
onfig_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\ttheiner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin
\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" configure --fallback
-to-build --module=C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt\l
ib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\tthei
ner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding )  else (node "" confi
gure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_m
odules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path
=C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT
HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.failNoPython (C:\Users\ttheiner\AppData\Roaming\npm
\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:454:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ttheiner\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:480:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\ttheiner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\nod
e_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ttheiner\\App
Data\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
 "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\ttheiner\\NodeProjects\\
authtest\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bc
rypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\ttheiner\\NodeProjects\\authtest\\node_modul
es\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallb
ack-to-build --module=C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcryp
t\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\tt
heiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeP
rojects\authtest\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/chi
ld_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\tthe
iner\\NodeProjects\\authtest\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "in
stall" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcryp
t
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.32
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\
ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node -
-module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\no
de_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding' (1)
npm WARN authtest@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN authtest@1.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ttheiner\\AppDat
a\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bcrypt" "--save"

npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.2 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallb
ack-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\npm-debug.log
```

The problem seems to be that npm cannot find pre-built binaries so it tries to compile the sources using python (which I don't seem to have).

Do I need to install python for this? If yes, can you point me in the right direction? Is it true that there is no pre-built version of bcrypt?

EDIT: After installing Python 2.7 the error changes... seems like it tries to use MSBuild to compile some C++ code.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir var
iable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number. [C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProject
s\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\no
de_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\ttheiner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)

gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ttheiner\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gy
p\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\ttheiner\\NodeProjects\\authtest\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding
\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\ttheiner\\NodeProjects\\authtest\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding
"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\no
de_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bc
rypt\lib\binding' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.
js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ttheiner\\NodeProjects\\authtest\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bi
n\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.32
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'node-gyp.cmd build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\b
crypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding' (1)
npm WARN authtest@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN authtest@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules'
npm WARN     at Error (native)
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\node_modules\dashdash\node_modules'
npm WARN     at Error (native)
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'scandir',
npm WARN   path: 'C:\\Users\\ttheiner\\NodeProjects\\authtest\\node_modules\\dashdash\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ttheiner\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "instal
l" "bcrypt" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.2 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ttheiner\NodeProjects\authtest\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: `Python 2.x` is listed as an explicit dependency on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), so I doubt you can get away without it.

Comment: Strange, after installing Python 2.7 the error changes. See latest edit

Comment: See [node-gyp documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp) inatallation requirements on windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you use bcrypt-nodejs:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs

It provides almost the same functionality with easy usage.

***Original answer:***

Can you try the following:

1. Install Python (http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/)
2. Install Visual Studio 2012/13 Express (or other)
3. Install Windows SDK (for Windows 7 / 8)
4. Install Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1g
5. Open "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012" as Administrator and test install

Then:

- `npm install node-gyp -g`
- `npm install bcrypt -g`

Comment: Nope, same result

Comment: @devnull69 can you please try the things i said in the recent edit

Comment: bcrypt-nodejs is the winner

Comment: See @Whymarrh's answer. Need to `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` first, then install `bcrypt`.

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same or at least a similar error.
Running the following before trying to install bcrypt solved it for me:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same issue today whilst trying to install bcrypt on Windows 10 desktop. Turns out that bcrypt support stable versions of node better check out the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)

The solution for me was:

1. Upgrade node to a stable version: I manually downloaded and installed Windows installer from Node website.
2. Install the Windows build tools globally: `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`
3. Finally `npm install bcrypt --save`

After this everything worked ok.

Comment: > Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error.

[image]

I reinstall node-gyp using this command  `npm install node-gyp -g`
after that I reinstall bccrypt using `npm install bcrypt`
And finally works

Answer (score 0):

When working on the node API project.

Solution

> rm -rf node_modules/bcrypt
>
> npm install node-gyp -g
>
> npm install bcrypt@[VERSION] -g

**it's working for me on window 10.**